# Which hashing method should I use for large text? - PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, hash

Most of the text stored in my DB is from 1MB to 1.5MB big. But not bigger then 1.5MB, because that's the limit I set.

Here are my needs:

- I need it for lowering my mysql database size
- I need it to be as fast as possible
- no security needed
- it must just work correctly, so that string_1 and string_2 can never have the same hash

I use PHP and MYSQL.

Comment: Are you looking for a hash or compression algorithm?

Comment: You can't lower the size of your DB by adding more data, so what do you intend to do with those hashes? What do they represent? What kind of data are you hashing? Is there an upper and lower limit to the byte length of that data? As for the last point: that's impossible. The pigeon hole principle tells us that if the hashing function reduces the size of your data, then there will be collisions possible. That's the essence of hashing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#Uses_and_applications).

Comment: Well, a hash is ususaly ireversible. It would have been super awesome to make a 1.5mb large file into a 32 characters long string tho!

Comment: No. You cant hash and un-hash like that. You can compress the text and get it down to smaller size, but not into that kind of size. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash is not reversible. You can make a 1.5MB text into a small string with the help of hashing, but you cannot convert the same hash back into the original text.

What you are looking for is a compression algorithm. You can make the files a lot smaller with compression, but it's unlikely to be as small as a hash.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest SHA1, as it is also in use by git and similar applications to identify strings.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1
and: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

```
$hash = hash( 'sha1', $inputData );
```

Answer (score 1):

### Saving space

- MySQL has built-in [`COMPRESS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress) and [`UNCOMPRESS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_uncompress) functions which will save space in your DB, as well having to write extra PHP code.

### Checking unique-ness

- Instead of indexing `TEXT` columns [regardless of if they're compressed or not] you can store and index 2 relatively-small things that will guarantee that that text is unique.

  1. A hash of the data, MD5, SHA, whatever you want.
  2. The length of the uncompressed data.
- For most hashing functions you're more likely to get hit by a meteor than have 2 identical hashes for different text strings, and having 2 indentical length and hash strings is less likely than getting hit by a meteor *and* lightning while winning three simultaneous lotteries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want a compression algorithm to reduce the text size.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php.